# How to reboot Windows 10 [UEFI] after installation of Linux (Fedora) in Legacy mode?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, reboot, partition-recovery, fedora-24

Recently I tried installing Linux in my laptop to dual boot with Windows 10, but I accidently did it in Legacy mode. I created a separate partition with 20gb for Linux and installed it in that partition. Through Linux I know that none of my other drives are affected as all the files are intact.

I'm able to use Linux through Legacy boot with no problems. I'm unable to boot Windows through UEFI boot configuration as it throws a "disk not found" error.

Q: Can someone please help me reboot to Windows 10???

Laptop Details:
Acer Aspire
8gb RAM
2.6 GHz
700gb Drive

PS: If solution requires Fedora to be uninstalled, that would not be a problem.

Comment: What bootloader do you see Windows bootloader or GRUB? You may repair grub in dual boot mode. See this:: https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem which occurs when a Linux OS is installed beside a Windows installation. **GRUB**, the [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bootloader) that Linux uses, cannot recognise a Windows installation, and hence on booting a blank screen is shown.

Use the Windows Repair CD, and run startup repair. The problem will be automatically fixed. A fresh Windows bootloader will be written, which recognises GRUB and hence, can dual-boot Linux.

If you do not have the Windows Repair CD, download the ISO image on another computer and make a bootable USB (using, I recommend, *Rufus*).

NOTE that installing Windows 10 in Legacy mode (*i.e.* the mode Windows 7 uses) is irrelevant to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try the procedure you have mentioned above. Although I have a few follow up doubts.

Comment: @KarthikCottur What are your doubts?

Comment: Firstly, should I uninstall Linux before using repair CD? Because it looks like Linux is blocking out Windows. Secondly, can I use the ISO disk provided by Microsoft on their website for repairing purpose? If so, will it recognise existing windows on my laptop or will I have to install as if it were new?

Comment: @Karthik -- No, you do not need to uninstall Linux (Linux is not *blocking* Windows; the bootloader was simply deleted during installation). On running Microsoft's Startup Repair, a fresh bootloader will be written on your disk which will enable you to dual-boot Windows and Linux. 

As to your next question, Startup Repair will detect the existing installation of Windows, and you should *never ever* need to perform a full re-installation.

Comment: I think the solution works for an UEFI installation, because it did not help in legacy. Although I backed up my data and reinstalled windows from scratch. Thanks for the help though, I will refer for future Linux installations.